# How to multiply a sparse matrix by a dense martix with eigen?

Tags: c++, eigen

I am trying to multiply a sparse matrix by a dense matrix in Eigen in C++ (the dimensions of course match). The following doesn't seem to work.

Here is a MWE:

```
  #include <Eigen/Dense>
  #include <Eigen/Sparse>

  using namespace Eigen;

  int main()
  {
        SparseMatrix<double> s;
        s.resize(3,3);
        MatrixXf d(3,3);

        MatrixXf d2(3,3);

        // gives an error
        s*d

        // doesn't give an error
        d*d2
 }
```

EDIT: The page here suggests that it should work smoothly, yet it doesn't... http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialSparse.html

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is is not sparse-dense, but rather mixed types, Xhich isn't allowed. Your sparse matrix is of type `double` while the dense matrices are of type `float` (MatrixX**F**). Change MatrixXf to MatrixXd (or cast to double) and it works fine.